# Как сохранить результат select а?

Tags: jquery-form

В общем ка сохранить результат select для последующей работы с ним.? А то он сбрасывается на начальный пункт.

```
$('#selectTerritory').change(function(){
        var selectTerritory= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            data: {Territory:selectTerritory},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#detale').html(data);
            }
        });
    });


$('form').on('change', '#selectRayons',function () {
    var selectRayons = $('#selectRayons').val();
    var selectTerritory = $('#selectTerritory').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "registration.php",
        data: {Rayons: selectRayons,Territory:selectTerritory},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#detale').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: А что конкретно должно сохраняться и что вы подразумеваете под "результат select"? Если нужно сохранять какую-то глобальную переменную, можно просто объявлять её за пределами функции - т.е. глобально, а в функции использовать уже без `var`

Comment: Плюсом к этому - раз вы используете ajax, советую события вешать на документ, а именно - `$(document).on('change', 'form #selectRayons', function(){})` В таком случае события будут вешаться и на элементы, добавленные скриптами уже после загрузки документа. Иначе если вы обновите DOM элемент form  - перестанет срабатывать событие

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно послать результат селекта дальше в скрипт, а пользователю Показать что его выбор - такойто. У меня же послылает дальше результат выбора, но  покаывает как будто бы обнавляется список который только что был отправлен.

Comment: А вас `#detale` это сама форма или ее содержание?

Comment: <form>
<input >
 <input >
<span id='detale'>сюда все появляется по задумке может тут кроется проблема?</span>
</form>

Comment: тогда вам не нужно сохранять никуда, а обновлять только `#selectRayons` в первом аяксе. И второй вариант - на сервере ставить выбранную страну

Comment: либо кстати вообще в лоб, после `$('#detale').html(data);` добавьте `$('#selectTerritory').val(selectTerritory);`

Comment: либо кстати вообще в лоб, после $('#detale').html(data); добавьте $('#selectTerritory').val(selectTerritory); ПОМОГЛО!!! спасибо!!!

Comment: Если у вас этот селект лежит в #detale - то проблема как раз из-за того что не вешаете события на `$(document)` - а вообще, если бы вы показали живой пример - то я бы мог подсказать в чем проблема и как более "корректно" её решить.

Comment: даже не знаю как показать то?

Comment: Я поменял событие на $(document) и в итоге получилось все гут.